# Implicit OAuth flow puts the access token in the hash?

Tags: support, api-v2.2, oauth2

The implicit OAuth flow puts the access token in the hash.
However, I would like to get that in the query (from `example.com/hi#access_token=123456` to `example.com/hi?access_token=123456`) for it to work with my application.

How can I do this? Is there a third-party method for this? Or can I do something to get the `access_token` in the query instead of the hash?

Comment: If you want the server to get the response why wouldn't you use the explicit flow instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't get the `access_token` in the query/search part of the URL.  **This would be a security leak** that would allow 3rd parties to see your `access_token`s on the web.
Reference:

- [OAuth2.0 Implicit Grant flow. Why use url hash fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733863/oauth2-0-implicit-grant-flow-why-use-url-hash-fragments)
- [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2.2)

**If your app is running on a server, use [the explicit OAuth flow][3].**

This returns a one-time `code` to your server -- in the URL query -- which you then POST to `/oauth/access_token` and receive an SSL encrypted response with the `access_token`.